ISC BIND named 9.19.24 / Disable AAAA/HTTPS lookups?
I have an instance of ISC BIND named mentioned version which acts as resolver of local domains and forwarder for external domains to the upstream ISP DNS server which is neither IPv6 nor DNS-overs-HTTPS capable. So my server is logging a ton of messages like this:
FORMERR resolving 'somedomain.tld/AAAA/IN': ISP.IP.DNS.ADDR#53
FORMERR resolving 'somedomain.tld/HTTPS/IN': ISP.IP.DNS.ADDR#53

My question is what is the right way and how to configure, what to put in the named.conf to stop these AAAA and HTTPS requests altogether and turn off such lookups completely?

What in the world... It's quite normal to lack IPv6 connectivity, but it's incredibly weird to lack support for AAAA record type – most DNS software was updated to support AAAA records well over 25 years ago. I have to suspect the DNS server is reacting badly to other DNS extensions... Can you test whether dig @isp.ip.dns.addr somedomain.tld AAAA works with 1) +noedns, 2) +edns=0 +nocookie, 3) +edns=0 +cookie? While at it, can you test whether the same works against other DNS servers (e.g. public 1.1.1.1)?
